# Can Graph3D[] use Tubes for edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

Can one modify the default `Graph3D[]` display to use 3D tubes for
the edges? E.g., how could one modify this simple display

```
Graph3D[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}]
```

to use (possibly thick) tubes or cylinders for the edges?
I would think `EdgeStyle->{?}` might accomplish this, but I can't see
how to do it. It appears the vertices are true 3D spheres, so this should
somehow be possible...

Ultimately I would like a "solid" representation of a 3D graph.

Comment: Something like: `Graph3D[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (Tube[#, .02] &)]`?

Comment: It does use tubes by default, they are just thin.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @CarlWoll:

         
[image: Tubes]

```
Graph3D[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (Tube[#, .065] &),
 VertexSize -> Medium]
```